# toDataURL canvas drawImage

Tags: security, canvas, cross-domain, drawimage

I'm trying to make an app that captures screenshots from webcam feeds. I have a bunch of curated URLs of webcams that I'm trying to load into a canvas which I can then save using toDataURL. The problem is, when I use drawImage from a URL with a different origin, Chrome and Firefox throw security errors. Is there any way to get around this / is there something else I can use?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use limited proxy ([nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/) will be smart and powerfull solution) at the same domain or to make a server-side script which will prepare and/or cache images (if data reusable, need some protection, etc). In specific conditions there available [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)